# Unable to conect oci8 driver with oracle 19c database with php 8.1

Tags: oracle12c, oracle19c, oci8, php-8.1

I'm trying to connect to oracle 19c database with 12c client with php version 8.1.getting below error.

**Message: str_replace(): Passing null to parameter #3 ($subject) of type array|string is deprecated
Filename: oci8/oci8_driver.php
Line Number: 160**

Is there anything Ineed to install.I'm using 12c client(administrator)

Comment: That is not an error. It's a deprecation notice saying that the code will need to be changed some time between now and PHP 9.0, which is probably at least 3 years away. It will make no difference to the functioning of your program.

Comment: oci8_driver.php is part of your application or framework (Codeigniter??) code.  If it's a framework, you could see if there is a newer version of the framework.  Or you could change your php.ini to not show deprecation messages.